# Cordova/Phonegap: Can't get Facebook Phonegap plugin to work

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I tried creating a Cordova/Phonegap app and adding the Facebook plugin, but alert(typeof facebookConnectPlugin); shows undefined:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
cordova platform add ios
cordova -d plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="1415347585409217" --variable APP_NAME="Test"
vi www/index.html  # Add: alert(typeof facebookConnectPlugin); to the last <script>
cordova emulate ios
```

Expected: The emulator shows "Object" in the alert dialog.

Actual: The emulator shows "undefined" in the alert dialog.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Devgeeks for his answer below.

Here are a couple of other things I needed to do to get it working:

1) Install the newer "develop" branch of the plugin:

```
cordova -d plugin add "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin#develop" --variable APP_ID="1415347585409217" --variable APP_NAME="Test"
```

2) Add the following below the opening  tag:

```
<!-- fb-root is needed by the FB API. -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

3) If you want FB login to work in the browser (for testing), copy www/js/facebookConnectPlugin.js into your app. Then include it before the closing  tag:

```
<script src="facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>
```

Then add the following to your  section:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      if (!window.cordova) {
        // Initialize - only executed when testing in the browser.
        facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(308939305080);
      }
  }
</script>
```

If you get "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.", edit facebookConnectPlugin.js and change sdk.js to sdk/debug.js .

4) If you get the following while building the app for Android:

```
sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var
```

try running the following (from [Issue 432](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/432)):

```
cp platforms/android/local.properties platforms/android/FacebookLib
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Add: alert(typeof facebookConnectPlugin); to the last <script>`

That is behaving as expected, believe it or not.

Plugins are not available till the `deviceready` event has fired: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

Try checking for the `facebookConnectPlugin` in the `onDeviceReady` of the generated `www/js/index.js` instead of an immediately fired  tag?

Comment: It would be nice if this were documented somewhere in the phonegap documentation. I didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, it should probably be somewhere in there. Each of the core Cordova plugins states at the top of their docs that the plugin will not be available till `deviceready` fires, but then that leaves it up to each third party plugin's docs to do the same. That's not great. There really should be somewhere that up front states that _all_ plugins must wait for `deviceready`.

Answer (score 2):

Hello guys i have found something new for Facebook integration in phone gap application, Without any Facebook plugins you can use Facebook functionality,for that use phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser.js using this js you can easily access all Facebook functionality for more information visit this URL : [Facebook Integration Step without any plugins](https://github.com/caiovaccaro/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser)

Comment: Hello, do you have any idea if it works both on android and ios apps?

Comment: Also, is it possible to get the first and last names? Now I can get only the complete name.